# Linqer cannot convert: SQL syntax error: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column reference

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6, linqer

I have this running query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       b.NAME AS [Service Name],
       CASE
           WHEN [a].[PAY_MODE_ID] IN ( 1, 2 ) THEN
               'OFFLINE'
           ELSE
               'ONLINE'
       END AS [Transaction Type],
       p.NAME AS [Payment Method],
       SUM(a.REQUESTED_QTY) AS [Transaction],
       SUM(a.ITEM_TOTAL) AS Income
FROM dbo.BILL_INFO_DETAIL AS a
    INNER JOIN dbo.SERVICE_INFO AS b
        ON a.SERVICE_CODE = b.SERVICE_CODE
    INNER JOIN dbo.PAY_MODE AS p
        ON a.PAY_MODE_ID = p.PAY_MODE_ID
WHERE (a.INPUT_STATUS = '1')
      AND (b.SERVICE_CODE IN ( 1610, 1611, 1612 ))
      AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), a.STAMP_DATE, 101) IN ( '10', '11', '12' ))
      AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), a.STAMP_DATE, 102) IN ( '2017' ))
      AND (b.FEE > 1)
GROUP BY b.NAME,
         CASE
             WHEN [a].[PAY_MODE_ID] IN ( 1, 2 ) THEN
                 'OFFLINE'
             ELSE
                 'ONLINE'
         END,
         p.NAME
ORDER BY [Transaction Type];
```

Linqer is not able to convert this to proper LINQ:

> SQL syntax error: Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column reference.

This query is working in SQL Server. Any pointers?

**Note:**

- Removing the `DISTINCT` has no effect
- Removing the `ORDER BY` has no effect
- Removing the `;` has no effect

Comment: lol - stick with SQL Server then, its faster and less work.

Comment: @AleksAndreev : Yes. It is found at http://www.sqltolinq.com/ I was thinking about start up a new tag for it but I was surprised no one has created one yet there are so many questions.

Comment: I'm with @buffjape

Comment: @buffjape I can't in this case. The amount of the WHERE clause customization that it heading to this view's way is too much to leave as a text query

Comment: Removing the `DISTINCT` has no effect

Comment: What version of Linqer are you using?

Comment: Also, see if it works without the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: @RBarryYoung v4.6

Comment: So what answer do you expect? How to convert it by hand? How to make Linker do it? If the latter - better ask their support I guess.

Comment: Convert it by hand. BTW, what SQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that all I had to do was to remove the CASE with PAY_MODE_ID. I modified the query apart from that change in order to make it production ready:

```
SELECT si.SERVICE_CODE,     
       si.NAME AS [ServiceName],
       bid.PAY_MODE_ID AS [PaymentId],
       p.NAME AS [PaymentName],
       SUM(bid.REQUESTED_QTY) AS [Transaction],
       SUM(bid.ITEM_TOTAL) AS [Income]
FROM BILL_INFO_DETAIL AS bid
    INNER JOIN dbo.SERVICE_INFO AS si
        ON bid.SERVICE_CODE = si.SERVICE_CODE
    INNER JOIN dbo.PAY_MODE AS p
        ON bid.PAY_MODE_ID = p.PAY_MODE_ID
WHERE (bid.INPUT_STATUS = '1')
      AND (si.SERVICE_CODE IN ( 1610, 1611, 1612 ))
      AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), bid.STAMP_DATE, 101) IN ( '10', '11', '12' ))
      AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), bid.STAMP_DATE, 102) IN ( '2017' ))
      AND (si.FEE > 1)
GROUP BY si.SERVICE_CODE,
         si.NAME,   
         bid.PAY_MODE_ID,
         p.NAME
```

This resulted in LINQ (slightly modified):

```
    from bid in db.BILL_INFO_DETAIL
    where
      bid.INPUT_STATUS == true &&
      (new int[] {1610, 1611, 1612 }).Contains(bid.SERVICE_INFO.SERVICE_CODE) &&
      (new int[] {10, 11, 12 }).Contains(bid.STAMP_DATE.Value.Month) &&
      bid.STAMP_DATE.Value.Year == 2017 &&
      bid.SERVICE_INFO.FEE > 1
    group new {bid.SERVICE_INFO, bid, bid.PAY_MODE} by new {
      bid.SERVICE_INFO.SERVICE_CODE,
      bid.SERVICE_INFO.NAME,
      bid.PAY_MODE_ID,
      Column1 = bid.PAY_MODE.NAME
    } into g
    select new {
      g.Key.SERVICE_CODE,
      ServiceName = g.Key.NAME,
      PaymentId = g.Key.PAY_MODE_ID,
      PaymentName = g.Key.NAME,
      Transaction = (int?)g.Sum(p => p.bid.REQUESTED_QTY),
      Income = (decimal?)g.Sum(p => p.bid.ITEM_TOTAL)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

For translating SQL to LINQ query comprehension:

1. Translate `FROM` subselects as separately declared variables.
2. Translate each clause in LINQ clause order, translating monadic and aggregate operators (`DISTINCT`, `TOP`, `MIN`, `MAX` etc) into functions applied to the whole LINQ query.
3. Use table aliases as range variables. Use column aliases as anonymous type field names.
4. Use anonymous types (`new {` ... `}`) for multiple columns.
5. `JOIN` conditions that aren't all equality tests with `AND` must be handled using `where` clauses outside the join, or with cross product (`from` ... `from` ...) and then `where`
6. `JOIN` conditions that are multiple `AND`ed equality tests between the two tables should be translated into anonymous objects
7. `LEFT JOIN` is simulated by using `into` *joinvariable* and doing another from `from` the *joinvariable* followed by `.DefaultIfEmpty()`.
8. Replace `COALESCE` with the conditional operator (`?:`)and a `null` test.
9. Translate `IN` to `.Contains()` and `NOT IN` to `!`...`Contains()`, using literal arrays or array variables for constant lists.
10. Translate *x* `BETWEEN` *low* `AND` *high* to *low* `<=` *x* `&&` *x* `<=` *high*.
11. Translate `CASE` to the ternary conditional operator `?:`.
12. `SELECT *` must be replaced with select range_variable or for joins, an anonymous object containing all the range variables.
13. `SELECT` fields must be replaced with `select new {` ... `}` creating an anonymous object with all the desired fields or expressions.
14. Proper `FULL OUTER JOIN` must be handled with an extension method.

So for your query,

```
var ans = (from a in dbo.BILL_INFO_DETAIL
           join b in dbo.SERVICE_INFO on a.SERVICE_CODE equals b.SERVICE_CODE
           join p in dbo.PAY_MODE on a.PAY_MODE_ID equals p.PAY_MODE_ID
           where (a.INPUT_STATUS == "1") &&
                 (new[] { 1610, 1611, 1612 }.Contains(b.SERVICE_CODE)) &&
                 (new[] { 10, 11, 12 }.Contains(a.STAMP_DATE.Month)) &&
                 (new[] { 2017 }.Contains(a.STAMP_DATE.Year)) &&
                 (b.FEE > 1)
           let TransactionType = new[] { 1, 2 }.Contains(a.PAY_MODE_ID) ? "OFFLINE" : "ONLINE"
           group new { a, b, p } by new { bName = b.NAME, TransactionType, pName = p.NAME } into abpg
           orderby abpg.Key.TransactionType
           select new {
               Service_Name = abpg.Key.bName,
               TransactionType = abpg.Key.TransactionType,
               Payment_Method = abpg.Key.pName,
               Transaction = abpg.Sum(abp => abp.a.REQUESTED_QTY),
               Income = abpg.Sum(abp => abp.a.ITEM_TOTAL)
           }).Distinct();
```